# Rendering Views as String with Spring MVC and Apache Tiles

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, view, tiles

I am trying to reuse some of my tiles in a controller which is returning a json response to the client. I would like to return a json response similar to the following format:

```
{ 
 'success': <true or false>,
 'response': <the contents of an apache tile>
}
```

In my controller I would like to perform logic similar to this pseudocode:

```
boolean valid = validator.validate(modelObj)
String response = ""
if(valid){
     response = successView.render() // im looking for a way to actually accomplish        
                                     // this, where the successView is the apache tiles view.
                                     // I would also need to pass a model map to the view somehow.
}else{
     response = errorView.render() 
}
writeJsonResponse(httpResponse, /* a Map whose json representation looks like the one I described above. */)
```

Comment: I think that sending html code in json is not a good idea. If you just want to know if the request has succeed or not you can look at the response status code (and change it to any value in the server) and send from the server the view as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I belive that you want to implement a view class that will wrap the output of a jsp in json.  The class in question may be `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView`.

Another option may be to extend the JSON converter.  `org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to render the view using **Apache Tiles 2**, you must use

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver
```

See the example tutorial here: http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-mvc-3-tiles-2-integration.html

If you need to render the response as JSON, you can use the *@ResponseBody* which requires Jackson in your classpath. See the example here http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/01/spring-mvc-3-and-jquery-integration.html (The controller returns JSON). You can also see a similar example of the @ResponseBody at http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/jqgrid-and-spring-3-mvc-integration.html